# nginx Reverse proxy can't access some sites

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have installed nginx to use as reverse proxy in my private network.

Everything works fine, except some sites like :

www.dhl.com (getting error 404 not found in console)

www.bbc.com (It will stay in a loop).

The conf is below:

```
    server {

  server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.access.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.error.log crit;
  listen 192.168.98.254:8081;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  location / {

        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass http://$domain;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;


    # Optional headers
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  }
}
```

Please any body know how to fix this kind of websites ?

Thanks,

Areeb

Comment: I think we need more context here. Why are you adding a reverse proxy on your own network for external websites? A reverse proxy is typically used as a load balancer, a redirection layer, to add rules to your website, and similar things, not as a proxy server. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That is not a reverse proxy, it is a forward proxy. Something that nginx is poorly suited for. Use a proper forward proxy, such as squid.

Comment: I am using nginx to use the "sub_filter" module in some websites to put customized banners / notification for connected users in my network.

Comment: I am redirecting the HTTP (TCP: 80) to this nginx server for several minutes just to show my notifications to my connected users on the network.

Comment: Any domain which starts with `www.` will not work properly, because you deliberately remove it from the `$domain` variable.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you Richard, I've tried to put www. manually before the $domain and that's solved the problem for (www.dhl.com). Please how can i pass the argument based on the user's request in RegExp like the "server_name" directive ?

Comment: You should use `$http_host` instead - which is the `nginx` variable representing the full domain name requested by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites need the www
so you should add a custom variable like below

```
server_name ~^(?<var>www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
```

and change this line

```
 proxy_pass http://$domain;
```

to

```
 proxy_pass http://$var$domain;
```